# Python: How to pass in only one variable into a lambda function?

Tags: python, lambda

My code is reading in a text file line by line. Each line is then trimmed of all whitespace to one space character and based on whether it matches the pattern it is then written to either the matched_data_file or the unmatched_data_file. I have to make use of lambda in this particular example. I think the error lies with the following line but I'm not 100% sure:

```
success(line=row) if pattern.match(line) else failure(line=row)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "model_dev_txt_to_csv.py",
>   line 26, in 
>       process(source_filename)   File "model_dev_txt_to_csv.py", line 23, in process
>       process_line(line, lambda: write_csv(m, line), lambda: write_csv(u, line))   File "model_dev_txt_to_csv.py", line 12, in
>   process_line
>       return success(line=row) if pattern.match(line) else failure(line=row) TypeError: () got an unexpected keyword
>   argument 'line'

The following is my current code:

```
import re
import csv

pattern = re.compile("([0-9]+) +([0-9\.-]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+) +([0-9\.\-+Ee]+)")
source_filename = "track_param_hist.txt"
matched_data_file = "good_hist_csv.csv"
unmatched_data_file = "bad_hist_csv.csv"

def process_line(line, success, failure):
    # Make sure all whitespace is reduced to one space character
    row = (' '.join(line.split())).split(' ')
    success(line=row) if pattern.match(line) else failure(line=row)

def write_csv(file, line):
    csv.writer(file).writerow(line)

def process(source):
    print("Script for splitting text file into two separate csvs...")
    with open(matched_data_file, 'w') as m:
        with open(unmatched_data_file, 'w') as u:
            with open(source) as f:
                for line in f:
                    process_line(line, lambda: write_csv(m, line), lambda: write_csv(u, line))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process(source_filename)
```

Comment: Your lambdas don't define *any* parameters - try e.g. `lambda line: write_csv(...)`

Comment: Or since they already have access to `line`, call them with no arguments.

Comment: Seeing as your `process_line` turns a `line` into a `row`, I think it'd be clearer if you used the name `row` as a variable from that point.  So the variable name in the lambda is `row` and doesn't shadow the original `line`

Comment: `success(line=row) if pattern.match(line) else failure(line=row)` doesn't make any sense. Maybe you mean `if pattern.match(line): success(line=row) else: failure(line=row)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda expression's [syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) in Python is:

```
lambda [list of arguments]: <expression>
```

In your code you do not have any arguments defined for your lambdas. You need to add an argument named `line` before the `:` character to make your code work:

```
lambda line: write_csv(m, line), lambda line: write_csv(u, line)
```